# How do I write query to insert SDO_GEOMETRY type column datain Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, geospatial, spatial, oracle-spatial

I have a task to create sql queries to insert data in oracle column.
The datatype is SDO_GEOMETRY 
I have only Latitude and Longitude values.

Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The full doc has more examples but here's the snippet you need.

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,
             4326,
             SDO_POINT_TYPE(37.783333, -122.416667, NULL),
             NULL,
             NULL)
```

Full Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18750/xe_locator.htm#XELOC563

Comment: Thanks Kris ! That's what I wanted !

Answer (score 0):

In addition to saving the Lat&Lng in the SDO_GEOMETRY column as [Kris Rice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3715100/kris-rice) said, you can use the many useful features of Oracle Spatial and Oracle Locator to achieve some useful results.

In order to use those features, the below steps must be taken:

1. Alter the table to add a geometry (SDO_GEOMETRY) column.
2. Update the table to populate the SDO_GEOMETRY objects using existing location-related data values.
3. Update the spatial metadata (USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA).
4. Create the spatial index on the table.

The detail of the above steps is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/spatially-enabling-table.htm#SPATL1514).

After the above steps have been done, you can use useful operators provided by Oracle Locator. For example, you can find the locations that are within X meters distance from a given point. For more details, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18750/xe_locator.htm#XELOC100) Oracle document.